# Tooltip for Splitcontainer ( Panel)

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I would like to show a tooltip, each time the mouse is over a specific splitcontainer panel. I do know, how to add mouseEvents, but I can't find a way to add a tooltip to a splitcontainer or any of it's panels.  Is there a way?

Comment: not really, the panel is visible all the time and it is not intended to collapse it

Answer (score 1):

Add `ToolTip` component on `Control` or `Form` where `SplitContainer` is.
Then on each panel of `SplitContainer` new property "ToolTip on toolTip1" will be available, then set tooltip message.